# Node.js Server Request to HTTPS Enough for Encryption?

Tags: node.js

After much googling I'm still just as lost as I was when I started. I'm trying to make a secure request from one server to another in Node.js, and I'm unsure if sending the request through https (ex: https://someapi.com) is sufficient. Both servers are owned by me. One server needs to ping the other for verification/authentication by sending an API key + secret to it. Would my request from the requesting server to the authentication server be encrypted? Or would it be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks?

I'm making the request from the main/requesting server like so:

```
const rpn = require('request-promise-native');

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://authenticationserver.com/api/verification',
  json: {
     api_key: API_KEY_HERE,
     secret: SECRET_HERE
  }
}

rpn(options)
.then((responseData) => console.log('successful'))
.catch((err) => console.log('error'));
```

Comment: It would be vulnerable if the clientside had turned off verification which does not seem to be the case. It is yet vulnerable to more very advanced attacks by the NSA unless you use certificate-pinning with secure or fixed DNS or if they do have physical access to your machines.

Comment: Are these cloud servers or physical servers?

Comment: @Bradley They would be cloud servers deployed to Heroku for now and possibly AWS in the future

Comment: @DanFromGermany I'm not quite sure what you mean by "if the clientside had turned off verification". Are you referring to the requesting server? And if so, how could I could confirm that verification is not turned off?

Comment: Clientside is always the place where you do the request. Validation by default is turned **on**. Turning it off would mean to set the option `rejectUnauthorized: false` or `insecure: true`. But don't do it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using HTTPS is sufficient for this task.

The primary purpose of a secure transport protocol (like HTTPS, SSH, WSS, etc.) is to make man-in-the-middle attacks very hard. Because of the nature of the internet you cannot control the machines that your data travels through, so it's nearly impossible to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack, unless of course you control the entire network of computers like an [intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet). Knowing this some very smart people invented [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to combat man-in-the-middle attacks.

Public-key cryptography exploits a feature of advanced number theory where the basic idea is that is very computationally expensive to factor very large prime numbers. Using this feature it is possible to generate two very large prime numbers, then using some complex mathematics you can encrypt data with one of the prime numbers in such a way that the only way to decrypt the data is to do the mathematic operation in reverse using the other prime number. These two prime numbers are referred to as public and private keys.

When two computers establish an HTTPS connection they share their public keys and negotiate an encryption cypher. Once a cipher is determined (like AES) an additional key must be generated by one of the computers and shared with the other, this is the key that will be used to encrypt and decrypt the actual traffic. This key, however, is first encrypted using the public key of the computer that will be receiving the key. The receiving computer then decrypts the key using it's private key and the process known as "handshake" is complete.

During this handshake you'll notice that the private keys are not shared over the network, this is the key to avoiding the man-in-the-middle attack. Because the private key is not shared the man-in-the-middle does not have the ability to decrypt the cipher key and therefor are unable to decrypt the remaining traffic sent over the connection.

---

If you want to be as secure as possible you should generate sufficiently large public/private keys, update the keys regularly, and disallow the negotiation of insecure cipher suites. You cannot prevent a man-in-the-middle attack, you can only make it more difficult for them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! It helped increase my understanding a great deal. I always thought the browser was in charge getting the public key from the server it was sending the request to, and by making the request directly from the server instead of the browser, this step wasn't being done. So, just clarify: because I am making this request to an https url, my request body isn't being sent in plain text and would require decryption for the API key and secret to be human readable, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The handshake occurs when the connection is established, the HTTP request follows and is fully encrypted.

Comment: Great! Just what I needed to know. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, in your case, HTTPS should be enough secure.

If you want to increase security, you can play with RSA, AES to encrypt and decrypt your payload before sending it.

Comment: "Playing" with plain algorithms most probably leads to implementing them wrong which might give the developer a good feeling where in fact the end-to-end encryption might be crackable.

Answer (score 0):

If these are cloud servers, and the communication is directly from server1 to server2, arrange the servers in the same VPN and block access from outside the VPN to the authentication server.

In AWS, you can use API Gateway to target specific routes on the authentication server allowing you to selectively expose routes for public (outside the VPN) consumption if you need that still.